# How to get this hydraulic system working and help identifying parts and their function

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, hydraulics, plastic, injection

I have recently acquired a 1982 Arburg 220-90-350 injection moulding machine, mainly just as a hobby to further my knowledge on injection moulding machines and control systems as I plan to modernise the control system by redesigning it from scratch using a PLC and HMI.

This is my first proper project involving hydraulics at this scale, the hydraulic pump motor works but I have no pressure at the hydraulic valves. There are two proportional valves on top of the pump, the pump has two large pipes connecting to the manifold and one small one.

What is the purpose of the proportional valves and do I control both at the same time, just one, if so what one? What is the small pipe doing, it is the small rubber hose connecting to the lower side of the pump?

I'm sure the control valves on the manifold are standard hydraulic valves and not proportional, is this right?

I'm thinking all I have to do is work out what the proportional values do on the pump and then control them and then control the valves on the manifold. Is this the right way of thinking?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Start with a hydraulic schematic, I say.

Comment: That's most definitely the plan when I have time to disassemble some parts to get better access to the pump and behind the manifold. The main thing I would like to know though is why there would be proportional valves on the pump its self, what they do and what to do with them

Comment: I've done a limited amount of moulding but there are at least two pressures that need to be controlled: clamp pressure and injection pressure. The regulators might feed back to the hydraulic pump to get it to regulate. Ask Arburg if they have the manual for the machine. See if https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CnIP85oY3o is of any help regarding regulating pumps.

Comment: If You can share clear Picture of the Hydraulic Drawing and Operation sequence chart I can explain